# How to add image button and label on main button dynamically in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-button, android-imagebutton

I want to create multiple buttons dynamically with label and another small button on it.      For example:-
[image][image]

Comment: Create Custom View by extending `View` and draw on canvas.

Comment: can you provide some graphical UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add drawable in button right.I think there is no need to add extra button on button if there is no action for upper button . please see below code and try

```
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(this);

parent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("Primary");
    Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.your_image);
    image.setBounds(0, 0, 60, 60);
    b.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, image, null);
    parent.addView(b);
}
```

If you face any issue .. let me know.. hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first of all make an item of Image button and label in xml.

**item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llOverallTitleDOWN"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then on java file refer the below code.

```
    LinearLayout llOverallTitleDOWN = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llOverallTitleDOWN);

    View layout2 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.item, llOverallTitleDOWN, false);

    ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) layout2.findViewById(R.id.imgBtn);
    TextView textLabel = (TextView) layout2.findViewById(R.id.textLabel);
    imgBtn.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    textLabel.setText("label");

    llOverallTitleDOWN.addView(layout2);
```